# TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) , I am using Tornado

Tags: tornado, wsgi, gunicorn

Executing the following command:

```
/usr/local/python_venv/bin/gunicorn --workers=2 app:app -b '0.0.0.0:5000'
```

Getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/python_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
File "/usr/local/python_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 171, in handle_request
respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I am using Tornado.

Comment: please post app, but I presume is the same issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484732/tornado-wsgi-wsgiapplication-issue-call-takes-exactly-3-arguments-2-given

Comment: I figured out the problem was in the gunicorn command:
    /usr/local/python_venv/bin/gunicorn -k tornado --workers=2 app:app -b '0.0.0.0:5000'

Comment: tornado worker:). Do not hesitate to post an answer.